# MetaData.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bind' when using sqlite

Tags: sqlite, jupyter-notebook

im very new to sqlite, im using macbook m1, im try to use jupyter notebook to do sql
here is my code

```
%load_ext sql

import csv, sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("socioeconomic.db")
cur = con.cursor()
```

everything is okay until this
but when i connect to the sqlite

```
%sql sqlite:///socioeconomic.db
```

there is error something like this

```
MetaData.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bind'
Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
               postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
               or an existing connection: dict_keys([])
```

do you have any suggestion what should i do?

i tried to use other laptop but windows, and the same code works, but in mac isnt

Answer (score 4):

Check out [this guide](https://jupysql.ploomber.io/en/latest/connecting.html)!
Essentially there are 2 ways you can connect from your Jupyter notebook to SQLite local db. I don't think it relates to your Mac version as I have M2 and it's running fine.

Check you have the .db file locally. Also, check if the same sqlalchemy versions are matching. I believe `pip install sqlalchemy==1.4.4` should work. Another reason to move to Jupysql is that it supports the latest SQLAlchemy version.

Here are 2 ways you can make it run via `Jupysql`:

1. You can pass your existing connections to `%sql` as follows:

```py
some_engine = create_engine("sqlite:///some.db")
%sql some_engine
```

2. You can connect directly to it:

```py
%sql sqlite:///foo.db
```

For both options you'll need to set up the correct package and import it via `%load_ext sql`

Comment: wow big thanks, after i tried to install install jupysql duckdb-engine it works somehow

Comment: That's awesome, feel free to accept the answer :)
You can also join our community, we'd love to hear your use case!
https://ploomber.io/community

Comment: Confirmed using jupysql fixed the issue, it's the fork of iphyton-sql. Command to install on conda `conda install jupysql -c conda-forge` (from their docs)

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to simply downgrade the SQLalchemy version. Mine was 2.0, so I rolled it back to version 1.4.39. To do this, head on to the environment tab, select and apply version 1.4.39. Make sure to restart the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

De-versioning worked for me. Sqlalchemy v2.0 --> v1.4.4